# R Subset data frame and perform function based on columns

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Sample data. I'm not sure how to use the code block system on SO yet.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),c(1990,1991,1992,1990,1991,1992,1990,1991,1992),c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3))
colnames(df) <- c("id", "year", "value")
```

That generates a simple matrix.

`id year value

  1 1990     1

  1 1991     2

  1 1992     3

  2 1990     3

  2 1991     2

  2 1992     1

  3 1990     2

  3 1991     1

  3 1992     3`

I was sorting through the R subsetting questions, and couldn't figure out the second step in  a ddply function {plyr} applied to it.

Logic: For all ID subgroups, find the highest value (which is 3) at the earliest time point.

I'm confused as to what syntax to use here. From searching SO, I think ddply is the best choice, but can't figure out how. Ideally, my output should be a vector of UNIQUE IDs (as only one is selected, with the entire row taken with it. This isn't working in R for me, but its the best "logic" I could come up with.

`ddply( (ddply(df,id)), year, which.min(value) )`

E.g.

`id year value

1 1992 3

2 1990 3

3 1992 3`

If 3 is not available, the next highest (2, or 1) should be taken.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that `ddply` splits your original data.frame into data.frames according to the splitting variable(s). Thus, it needs a function with a data.frame as argument and return value.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(id),function(DF) {res <- DF[which.max(DF$value),]
                             res[which.min(res$year),]})

#   id year value
# 1  1 1992     3
# 2  2 1990     3
# 3  3 1992     3
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't written many functions yet in R, so that is where I got caught up. If I understand it, ddply generates a data frame which can be manipulated by a function statement (as you placed above).

Comment: Exactly, `ddply` splits into data.frames, which get passed to the function. The function returns data.frames to `ddply` which in turn combines them.

Comment: I've returned to this function you wrote 4 times now - this was perfect, Roland.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `data.table` is the best tool for you (both for speed and syntactic reasons):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

# order by year, and then take the first row for each id that has max 'value'
dt[order(year), .SD[which.max(value)], by = id]
#   id year value
#1:  1 1992     3
#2:  2 1990     3
#3:  3 1992     3

# if you're after speed, this slightly worse syntax is the current way of achieving it
dt[dt[order(year), .I[which.max(value)], by = id]$V1]
```

Comment: This appears to have worked as well - it matched with what Roland posted in terms of results. Thanks so much eddi.